# How to access element from dynamically generated html

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask, jinja2

I'm having trouble accessing an element from a dynamically generated html template from flask. This is what I have.

#app.py

```
@bp.route('/something',method=['GET'])
def some_action():
     # does something 
     my_list = getList()
     return render_template("show_list_template.html",my_list=my_list)
```

#show_list_template.html

```
<table id="table" name="table">
    <tr>
        <th>List Header 1</td>
        <th>List Header 2</td>
    </tr>
    {% for item in my_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.0}}</td>
        <td>{{item.1}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

#main.html

```
  
  <label for="Description">Description</label>
  <textarea name="desc" id="desc">{{ request.form['desc'] }}</textarea>

  <hr align="left" width="100%" size="10" color="black">
  
  <div id="dynamic_list"></div>
  <button type="button" class="updateButton" id="updateBtn">Get New List</button>
```

#app.js

```
function getList(){
        $.ajax({
            url : './test',
            type : 'GET',
            success: function(response){
                $('#dynamic_list').html(response);
            },
            error : function(xhr){
                alert("Error occured")
            }
        });
              
    };

$("#table tr").on('click',function(){    
        var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
        console.log(value) 
        // Do something with value 
     });
```

The #table tr function doesn't work. If I place this same script inside the template.html file inside of a script tag it works, here but I need the script to work from app.js where the value from the table is needed for another function.

Comment: How did you link your app.js? Did you link it dynamically as mentioned in flask documentation. eg: <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='app.js')}}"></script>. Or did you linked it statically? Like <script src="app.js"></script>

Comment: @psychoSherlock the former ( url_for...)

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that your javascript is used before html dom is loaded , you should run the your click event after dom is loaded

For that you can use jquery ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// all you code goes here
});
```

or simple :

```
$(function(){
// your code goes here 
});
```

both are equivalent according to jquery docs.